# Does generation of debug information to JSP classes add much to javac execution time?

Tags: jsp, javac, jboss5.x

I am looking looking into the options for tweaking the performance of JBoss 5.1.0 and one of the options available to me is to disable the generation of debug information when compiling JSPs.

I know that the presence/absence of debug information for the JVM [makes no real difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218033/), but does the generation of that debug information add much to compile time?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: JSP are only compiled once after startup... is this really important to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't, but since a JSP is basically compiled into a large `try` block, this may reduce the risk to bump into the [64KB limit](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22code+too+large+for+try+statement%22).