# Why doesn't Slf4j/Logback log filename and row number

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm having problems with my logging where slf4j doesn't log the filename and row number of the message/stacktrace.

**Code:**

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeService.class);

@Override
public void aService(ServiceAdmin sa) throws Exception {
    log.debug(LoggerFactory.class.toString());
    log.debug(log.getClass().getName());
    log.debug("Setup Example");
    SomeService.setDefault(Example.getInstance());
    log.debug("Example finished");
}
```

**Log:**

```
2015-04-20 14:47:26.573 DEBUG [main] null:-1 - class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
2015-04-20 14:47:26.574 DEBUG [main] null:-1 - ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
2015-04-20 14:47:26.574 DEBUG [main] null:-1 - Setup Example
2015-04-20 14:47:26.575 DEBUG [main] null:-1 - SomeService finished
```

This is pars of my logback.xml that relates to this class

```
    <logger name="com.bredband.nexusgw.services">
            <level value="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="nexusservice" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="nexusservice"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <File>/var/log/nexus/nexusjgw/jgw/Service.log</File>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                    <FileNamePattern>/var/log/nexus/nexusjgw/jgw/Service.log.%i
                    </FileNamePattern>
                    <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
                    <MaxIndex>5</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <triggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                    <MaxFileSize>200MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                    <level>debug</level>
            </filter>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%t] %F:%L - %m%n</Pattern>
            </layout>
    </appender>
```

Has anyone seen this before and can point me in the right direction?

BR
Stefan

-- Update --

I changed the %F to %C, but that didn't change anything in the logs. Then I tried to set debug = "on" in the javac header in my ant file and now it's logging classname and line number.

```
2015-04-21 08:28:55.910 DEBUG [main] Service.java:20 - class     org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
2015-04-21 08:28:55.911 DEBUG [main] Service.java:21 - ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
2015-04-21 08:28:55.911 DEBUG [main] Service.java:22 - Setup Example
2015-04-21 08:28:55.912 DEBUG [main] Service.java:24 - Example finished
```

Although this is working, it's not something I've changed before. The only thing that has changed in this project over time is the addition of other external jars. I'm not really sure how adding a duplicate/newer/older version of slf4j in another external jar would affect the logging though, any version should look for the logback file?

-- Update --
After checking alot of historical checkins of the build.xml file I found that we actually had debug = "on" earlier and the problem may actually have been introduced by this parameter beeing set to "off".

Thank you for your help.

BR
Stefan

Comment: How about providing important information... like your logback config?

Comment: What have you put in your logback configuration file?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong at first glance. Have you done any recent changes to how the application is delivered/packaged/deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first make sure that you compile your application with debug information. If calling `javac` directly, then it is the `-g` command-line parameter. However most build tools (like maven or ant) have a specific way to provide this parameter.

You may also want to replace `%F` with `%C`, which should work without the debug information.

Comment: This solved the problem, but I guess debugging shouldn't have to be "on" for this to work, We havn't had debug = "on" in ant earlier.

Comment: You only have to compile with the debug flags, you don't need to run the application in debug mode. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218033/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-javac-debug-on-and-off